# File History Windows 11

Tags: windows-11

How do I reset the file History in Windows 11 on a new external drive. It starts the File History directory on the External drive, but complete before it copy any files.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have replaced the old External drive, that is shot with a new drive. When I changed the the 'select drive' to the new external drive, and 'turn on' the file history, it run for 5seconds but only creates a directory on the the external and did not copy any files.